# Eclipse Galileo/Helios There is no Mylyn View available under Window > Show View > Other

Tags: java, eclipse, mylyn

Eclipse Galileo/Helios  There is no Mylyn View available under Window > Show View > Other

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for Window -> Show View -> Task list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want to refer you to this article vogella.de/articles/Mylyn/article.html" , to see what i want! Task repositories Under the Mylyn in Show View